# Azure Mobile Services versus Custom API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, azure, azure-mobile-services

We currently have a MVC5 web application that has recently gone live. Much of the business logic is contained within GET and POST controller methods in C# files. A native iOS app is planned for the project and the concern was expressed that we must ensure that the business logic is the same for the web app and the mobile app. I'm asking for anyone with experienced with Azure Mobile Services to elaborate on how we can easily ensure consistency between the web app and the mobile in terms of backend business logic. I see two options as of right now: 1. Create an API project and ensure both the web app and the mobile app call the same endpoints 2. Integrate Azure Mobile Services and ensure that the business logic matches the web app at all times. I'm just looking for guidance.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are starting work now, I would start work with Azure Mobile Apps rather than Azure Mobile Services.  Azure Mobile Apps can provide a web app and a mobile-friendly API for you.

Azure Mobile Apps provides three distinct things on top of Azure Web Apps.  The first is a mobile-friendly data-sync capability.  This is a RESTful interface that provides access to data from a backend resource.  You can use it directly as a REST endpoint - great for your websites, but it is also an [OData](http://www.odata.org) source.  There are clients available for iOS (Objective-C/Swift), Xamarin (C#/.NET) and more coming that use this to provide a sync capability.  The addition of a SQLite store provides an offline sync capability that your mobile app can utilize for performance and network efficiency.

The second is authentication that works with the mobile data-sync capability.  This can be used across your web and mobile apps and links into enterprise authentication systems (via [Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/active-directory/)), Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and Microsoft Account.  One of the more interesting things you can do is provide personalized results - a user can only access their own records via data-sync.  Mobile authentication is different and the SDKs provided in addition will provide that functionality for you.

Finally, there is a pass-through for Notification Hubs - a powerful push notifications system that provides access to APNS (for iOS devices), GCM (for Android devices) and WNS (for Windows-based devices) as well as push capabilities to Chrome and Safari web apps, Baidu and Kindle.

Nothing stops you from doing all this from a standard MVC5 ApiController, but the wrapping of the client-side SDK plus the additional functionality of the table controller reduces the complexity of the code you have to write.